# Spark java error, i cant start the application

Tags: java, spark-java

i've using Spark framework, I just created the gradle project and added the spark dependency but when I start the application, it gives this error in console:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

my gradle.buid

```
plugins {
   id 'java-library'
}
repositories {
   jcenter()
}
dependencies {
  implementation group: 'com.sparkjava', name: 'spark-core', version: '2.9.3'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

and my main class

```
import static spark.Spark.*;

public class Library {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    get("/hello/:name", (request, response) -> {
        return "Hello: " + request.params(":name");
    });
  }
}
```

I use version 7.1 of gradle and java 11.0 , I've tried all versions of spark but I can't even test the application, can anyone know where the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about Apache Spark, But it seems that's not an error, It is just some warnings. I think your written program works, But you don't see anything on the console.
This warning message is reported when the org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder class could not be loaded into memory. This happens when no appropriate SLF4J binding could be found on the class path. Placing one (and only one) of slf4j-nop.jar slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar on the class path should solve the problem.